# How to remove upper gap from svg text

Tags: html, css, svg

So there's a gap above my svg that no matter the height this still persist. I did think of solutions to fix this such as setting y="22" and then setting a margin-top: 10px;. But, I more just want to find out what's wrong exactly and what's the proper way to fix this.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<style>
span.top { display:block;}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<span class="top">
<a href="https://www.google.com/" title="Home">
<svg width="70px" height="50px">
    <text x="0" y="50" font-family="arial" font-size="25">
        Home
    </text>
</svg>
</span> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the `y` value to 20 instead of 50

```html
<span class="top">
<a href="https://www.google.com/" title="Home">
<svg width="70px" height="50px">
    <text x="0" y="20" font-family="arial" font-size="25">
        Home
    </text>
</svg>
</span>
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I was planning on doing in the end as stated in the post. But the thing is I want there to be a gap but without the gap being clickable.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to change y="20" by dy="25" 
more info see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dy

Why 25? because its the font-size that you choose.

```html
<svg width="70px" height="50px" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin">
 <text x="0" dy="25" font-family="arial" font-size="25">
    Home
 </text>
</svg>
```

I also add the property preserveAspectRatio that could be useful for you too.

Comment: [preserveAspectRatio is ignored without a viewBox](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute)

Comment: your right @RobertLongson but I added that so he could look into it because may be useful ;)

Answer (score 0):

your way is correct instead of 50 for the Y you can put 20 for the Y then it will be fixed

```
<span class="top">
<a href="https://www.google.com/" title="Home">
<svg width="70px" height="50px">
    <text x="0" y="20" font-family="arial" font-size="25">
        Home
    </text>
</svg>
</span>
```